# Add DOM nodes to react hierarchy

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I insert a DOM node using vanilla javascript into a hierarchy of DOM nodes created by react such that React will not remove it when the state changes.

**Reason:**
I am developing a browser extension, and would like to tightly integrate with an existing site. The existing site uses React under the hood, and I would like to insert a node into the DOM.

**Issue:**
Inserting the node works, but as soon as some state in the react app changes, it removes the custom node from the DOM.

How can I insert and element which will not be removed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can (but you might be able to work around it).

React's *job* is, in large part, to reconcile the state of the DOM with the state of the React element tree the code using React gives it. After the code has "rendered" React elements, React "commits" that structure to the DOM, doing a diff between the structure the React element tree describes and the structure that's there: removing things that shouldn't be there, adding things that are missing, and updating things that should be there but need their state updated. When it does that, it will see the element you added, see that it's not supposed to be there, and remove it.

The first workaround that comes to mind for your use case is to add the element and use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for it being removed, adding it back if (when) it is.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. MutationObserver has some performance challenges so it's not a great fit for this, I am using CSS3 animation events to achieve a similar result, but I was trying to avoid attaching a watcher for every new DIV on the page

Comment: @major-mann - You only need one observer, at the root of whatever section of the page you need to watch. Yes, it will impact performance. It's basically an observer or polling, each of which has its issues... Also -- this probably goes without saying -- modifying the DOM of a page from the outside like that is really problematic, just about anything might go wrong with the page from its CSS rules to event handlers to ... :-)